# How to use Zonal Stats as Table tool with in-line variable substitution

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I have created a model to iterate a folder of 5 shapefiles to apply the Zonal Stats as Table tool to a raster.  My output table is saved as table%i% so i'm expecting it produce 5 tables (table0, table1, table2, table3, table4, table5).  However it keeps saving over the same table so I just get 'table0'.  Can anyone suggest where i'm going wrong?  Thanks.

--

## Import arcpy module

import arcpy

## Check out any necessary licenses

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

## Load required toolboxes

arcpy.ImportToolbox("Model Functions")

## Script arguments

v5_River_Shapefiles = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if v5_River_Shapefiles == '#' or not v5_River_Shapefiles:
    v5_River_Shapefiles = "M:\Dissertation\Data\5 River Shapefiles" # provide a default value if unspecified

## Local variables:

FeatureClass = v5_River_Shapefiles
table_i_ = FeatureClass
Name = v5_River_Shapefiles
Standard_Average_Annual_Rainfall_*SAAR* = "SAAR 5km (F)\Standard Average Annual Rainfall (SAAR)"

## Process: Iterate Feature Classes

arcpy.IterateFeatureClasses_mb(v5_River_Shapefiles, "", "POLYGON", "RECURSIVE")

## Process: Zonal Statistics as Table

arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(FeatureClass, "ID", Standard_Average_Annual_Rainfall_*SAAR*, table_i_, "DATA", "ALL")

Comment: Without looking at the code behind the model, it's difficult to pinpoint a particular problem, though your iterator is likely not being incremented after each run. Why don't you export (Model->Export->To Python Script) the model and post the code?

Comment: Hi Paul, Good suggestion.  Please find the code above.  Many thanks

Comment: OK I have cracked it.  I need to change the output table to table%name%